# How to make my 'Secret Number Game' replay without having to execute the code again?

Tags: python

Beginner in Python. I've been attempting to make my game give the user a 'play again?' option once the initial game is complete. The replay works if I failed to guess the number after 6 tries, however if I managed to guess the number and try to replay nothing happens.

```
import random

secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

userGuesses = 0
userInput = False

while userInput == False:

    print("Let's play a game!")
    print("I'll think of a number between 1 and 20 and you have 6 attempts to get it right.")
    print("What is your first guess?")

    while userGuesses <= 5:

        userInput = input()

        if int(userInput) > secretNumber:
            print("Too High! Try again!")
            userGuesses += 1

        elif int(userInput) < secretNumber:
            print("Too Low! Try again!")
            userGuesses += 1

        else:
            print("Congratulations! You guessed the secret number in " + str(userGuesses + 1) + " guesses!")
            print("Would you like to play again? Y or N")
            playGame = input()
            if playGame == "Y":
                userInput = False
                userGuesses = 0
            else:
                userInput = True
                print("Goodbye!")

    else:
        print("You have run out of guesses! The number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber) + ". Better luck "
                                                                                                     "next time!")

    print("Would you like to play again? Y or N")
    playGame = input()

    if playGame == "Y":
        userInput = False
        userGuesses = 0
    else:
        userInput = True
        print("Goodbye!")
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: just remove the input issue from the inner `while` loop and once the user guessed it break the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also define your game in a separate function. I'd do something like this:

```
import random

def play_game():
    secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

    userGuesses = 0
    userInput = False

    print("Let's play a game!")
    print("I'll think of a number between 1 and 20 and you have 6 attempts to get it right.")
    print("What is your first guess?")

    while userGuesses <= 5:
        userInput = input()

        if int(userInput) > secretNumber:
            print("Too High! Try again!")
            userGuesses += 1
        elif int(userInput) < secretNumber:
            print("Too Low! Try again!")
            userGuesses += 1
        else:
            print("Congratulations! You guessed the secret number in " + str(userGuesses + 1) + " guesses!")

    print("You have run out of guesses! The number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber) + ". Better luck "
                                                                                                 "next time!")


if __name__ == '__main__':            
    playGame = 'y'
    while playGame == 'y':
        play_game()
        playGame = input('Would you like to play again? [y/n] ').lower()

    print("Goodbye!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a break at the if where you're 'restarting' the game:

```
import random

secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)

userGuesses = 0
userInput = False

while userInput == False:

    print("Let's play a game!")
    print("I'll think of a number between 1 and 20 and you have 6 attempts to get it right.")
    print("What is your first guess?")

    while userGuesses <= 5:

        userInput = input()

        if int(userInput) > secretNumber:
            print("Too High! Try again!")
            userGuesses += 1

        elif int(userInput) < secretNumber:
            print("Too Low! Try again!")
            userGuesses += 1

        else:
            print("Congratulations! You guessed the secret number in " + str(userGuesses + 1) + " guesses!")
            print("Would you like to play again? Y or N")
            playGame = input()
            if playGame == "Y":
                userInput = False
                userGuesses = 0
                #Break here to exit while loop
                break
            else:
                userInput = True
                print("Goodbye!")

    else:
        print("You have run out of guesses! The number I was thinking of was " + str(secretNumber) + ". Better luck "
                                                                                                     "next time!")

    print("Would you like to play again? Y or N")
    playGame = input()

    if playGame == "Y":
        userInput = False
        userGuesses = 0
    else:
        userInput = True
        print("Goodbye!")
```

Hope this helps you!